Package polyglossia Error: The current latin font NotoSerifKhmer(0) does not contain the "Khmer" script
I am trying to translate “Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality”
Here is my repository https://github.com/srghma/hpmor/commit/f4bd7a6063c6610aaa6bf99c5c7724f0d307825b
when I do
$ make docker_build && make docker_run__latexmk

it outputs error
! Package polyglossia Error: The current latin roman font does not contain the
"Khmer" script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \khmerfont with \newfontfamily comma
nd.

How to fix it?
Here is my list of fonts
$ docker run -it -v ./:/app hpmor fc-list : family | grep Khmer
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer SemiBold
Khmer OS Metal Chrieng
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer ExtraBold
Khmer OS System
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer Thin
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer SemiBold
Khmer OS Muol Pali
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer ExtraCondensed Medium
Khmer Mondulkiri
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer ExtraCondensed SemiBold
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer SemiCondensed Black
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer ExtraCondensed
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer Condensed Black
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer ExtraCondensed ExtraLight
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer Condensed SemiBold
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer ExtraCondensed
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer SemiCondensed Thin
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer SemiCondensed
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer Condensed ExtraLight
Khmer OS Content
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer ExtraCondensed Light
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer Condensed Thin
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer SemiCondensed SemiBold
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer ExtraLight
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer Condensed Medium
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer Condensed ExtraBold
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer SemiCondensed Medium
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer SemiCondensed Thin
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer SemiCondensed ExtraBold
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer Light
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer ExtraCondensed Thin
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer ExtraCondensed Black
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer SemiCondensed Light
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer Medium
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer SemiCondensed SemiBold
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer ExtraLight
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer Condensed Light
Khmer OS
Noto Sans Khmer UI
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer ExtraCondensed Black
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer Medium
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer Black
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer SemiCondensed ExtraBold
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer ExtraCondensed Thin
Khmer OS Siemreap
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer SemiCondensed Medium
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer Condensed Medium
Noto Sans Khmer
Khmer OS Freehand
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer SemiCondensed
Khmer OS Muol
Khmer OS Muol Light
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer Black
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer SemiCondensed Black
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer Condensed Light
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer SemiCondensed Light
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer ExtraCondensed Light
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer Condensed Thin
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer ExtraBold
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer ExtraCondensed ExtraBold
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer ExtraCondensed SemiBold
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer Condensed SemiBold
Khmer OS Battambang
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer Thin
Khmer OS Bokor
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer ExtraCondensed ExtraLight
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer Condensed Black
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer ExtraCondensed Medium
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer ExtraCondensed ExtraBold
Noto Serif Khmer
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer SemiCondensed ExtraLight
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer Condensed
Khmer OS Fasthand
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer Condensed ExtraBold
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer SemiCondensed ExtraLight
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer Condensed ExtraLight
Noto Sans Khmer,Noto Sans Khmer Light
Noto Serif Khmer,Noto Serif Khmer Condensed

I have tried other fonts
e.g. \newfontfamily\khmerfamily[Scale=0.8,Script=Khmer]{Noto Serif Khmer} or \newfontfamily\khmerfamily[Scale=0.8,Script=Khmer]{Khmer Mondulkiri}
But the error is the same - font ... does not contain the "Khmer" script

welcome! can you provide minimal code we can use to reproduce the error? which engine are you using?

this might be related https://github.com/latex3/fontspec/issues/507#issuecomment-2072094388

Oh the error message says you need to define \newfontfamily\khmerfont but you have defined \newfontfamily\khmerfamily maybe that is all you need. But you should provide a small test example (not a github link to files that will change)

You did not provide an example but
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{khmer}

\newfontfamily\khmerfamily[Scale=0.8,Script=Khmer]{NotoSerif-Regular}
\begin{document}

\textlang{khmer}{x}

\end{document}

produces
! Package polyglossia Error: The current main roman font, lmroman10-regular,
(polyglossia)                does not contain the "Khmer" script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \khmerfont with \newfontfamily
(polyglossia)                command


If, as the error message states, you change the command name from \khmerfamily to \khmerfont then it runs without error. (I used the base Noto Serif which doesn't have Khmer, but that's not relevant here)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{khmer}

\newfontfamily\khmerfont[Scale=0.8,Script=Khmer]{NotoSerif-Regular}
\begin{document}

\textlang{khmer}{x}

\end{document}


yes, replacing khmerfamily with khmerfont everywhere worked !
